# username parameter is empty in loadUserByUsername(String username) - spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

This is my `UserDetailService`:

```java
public class StockUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StockUserDetailService.class);
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        logger.debug("entering loadByUserName");
        // MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("springsecurity");
        User user = userRepository.findOne(username);
        logger.debug("this is teh user ibzect ="+user);
        if (user == null) {
            logger.info("----------------------------------------------user name is "+username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("NAT FOUND");
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

But the `username` argument always comes as `null`. I saw tons of other posts on Stackoverflow with the same problem. Some of them say that it is because it expects the `username` and `password` as part of HTTP headers rather than a JSON.

But I don't think that is true because Spring Boot's default login page just has a simple form which does a `POST` request to `/login`. Which is what I am doing.

I don't understand the problem here.

PS: I have configured by `username` and `password` key names properly:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/signup**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/logout/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .usernameParameter("username").
            .passwordParameter("password");
}
```

Comment: I know it a long time ago but can you share the solution other than sending it through application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You send `username` and `password` parameter as JSON (content type `application/json`), but you have to send URL-encoded parameters (content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form):

> **4** The username must be present as the HTTP parameter named username
>
> **5** The password must be present as the HTTP parameter named password

Comment: this was my exact problems, running post request on postman with json

Answer (score 2):

In my case in the html file I wrote name = "email"
I solved it by renaming to "username" because loadUserByUserName expects string with name "username"

```
<div class = "form-group">
                    <label for ="username">Email </label>:
                    <input type="text" class = "form-control" id ="username" name = "email"
                           placeholder="Enter Email ID" autofocus="autofocus">
                </div>
```

to:

```
<div class = "form-group">
                    <label for ="username">Email </label>:
                    <input type="text" class = "form-control" id ="username" name = "username"
                           placeholder="Enter Email ID" autofocus="autofocus">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your database `username` is the `id` of the `User` entity?
Becasuse if not, and you only have a field called username then you have to write a magic method in your UserRepository which is
 `User findByUsername(String username);` and use it in your `StockUserDetailService` to retrieve the user from the db. The `findOne()` method expects the `id` as a parameter, and in your case it founds nothing with that `id`.

Comment: username is annotated with "@Id". And the problem is not about database finding it.  The the "username" itself is empty.

Comment: The problem can be mybe with your `configure`method's chain order.
Please try the following order:
`http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();`

Comment: Tried. Still empty username