# How to properly configure ldap authentication in spring boot? Every time I log in, it redirects to /login after calling /auth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

**NOTE**
Suggested answer didn't work.

I have the following configuration in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchBase("somevalue")
            .userSearchFilter("somevalue")
            .contextSource().url("somevalue").port("somevalue")
            .managerDn("somevalue").managerPassword("somevalue");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*.css", "/*.html", "/*.js", "/*.jpg").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/auth")
            .permitAll();
}
```

And this is my configuration in WebMvcConfigurer:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*.css", "/*.html", "/*.js", "/*.jpg")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/", "/login", "/myapp")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/index.html")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) {
                    if (resourcePath.startsWith("/api") || resourcePath.startsWith("/api".substring(1))) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return location.exists() && location.isReadable() ? location : null;
                }
            });
}
```

WHen I click on login button I send the following request in angular:

```
this.http.post(`localhost:8080/auth`, {username: 'user', password: 'password'})...
```

But I only got redirected to /login.  Here's the network console:

```
auth                        302
login                       200
```

Here's the request (/auth) headers and body:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 47
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: JSESSIONID=*****somecookie*****
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/login
```

Payload:

```
{username: "user", password: "password"}
```

General:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/auth
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2019 10:49:09 GMT
Expires: 0
Location: http://localhost:8080/login
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

And here's when it redirects to /login:

General:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Request:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=*****somecookie*****
Host: localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/login
```

Basically, the response body is the content of my index.html.

And in the console it says:

```
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse...
headers: e {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/login"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/login"
```

Also, is my ldap config correct?
How to properly configure for ldap authentication?

**UPDATE**
As per recommendation, I changed my code to send the body as http params.  The request is now this:

Request Headers:
`Content-Type: application/x-www.form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`

Form Data
`username=user&password=password`

It still the same issue

Comment: i update the question, added the request headers.  after it redirects to /login, the response body is the content of my index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [username parameter is empty in loadUserByUsername(String username) - spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978548/username-parameter-is-empty-in-loaduserbyusernamestring-username-spring-boot)

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json` is wrong, see my answer of the other question.

Comment: actually, i am already sending as per required, what I showed earlier is the parsed view, the value is actually: username=user&password=password.  I updated my question above

Comment: Could you add Spring Security's log with `DEBUG`level enabled for the authentication request?

Comment: i think because I'm not sending the csrf.  I disable csrf through `http.csrf().disable()` and the request goes in.  However, after successfully validating with ldap, i got a return error response for the method `/login`: `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my question is the missing csrf.  If I don't disable csrf, spring security seems to look for this, otherwise, my request gets rerouted back to login page.  I fixed by adding the following:

```
http.csrf().disable()
```

For the `Request method 'POST' not supported` during `/login`, in my `AuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess()`, I put

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(targetURI).forward(request, response);
```

Instead, I just set the reponse with a string value:

```
response.getOutputStream().println(mapper.writeValueAsString(data));
```