# Spring authentication process fails

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

Good morning,

I am using Spring Security in order to secure a web application, the problem comes in the authentication process. The flow start from the login page (displayed correctly), when I type in "2" as a username and "ciao" as a password (I explain ho I defined it later), I am redirected to the login failed page and it seems no users where saved in the Database (although no errors or exception are shown in logs).

I have a database table (MySQL is used) and I want to authenticate users using it, the table construction script is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SR002`.`utenti` (
  `id_utente` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cognome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `qualifica` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_utente`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

where:

- id_utente: is used to retrieve the authentication record from the DB (it is actually a kind of username);
- qualifica: is used to set authorities for each user (ex. if "qualifica" = "admin", the user has admin privileges).

I manually added a record encrypting password with BCryptEncoder:

- id_utente = 2
- nome = name
- cognome = lastName
- password = $2y$04$atmkYeXsf8f7R6c7LU5fZ.lTuae5Pem3c303mG3P6UVbWMLxtgrSK (it is the hashed word "ciao")
- qualifica = admin

I found out that spring security provides JDBC authentication for this purpose and following tutorials on the internet I come up with the following configuration and userful classes.

**Security configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("securityUserDetailService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * Manages the encoder to save passwords in the DB
     * not in plain text
     *
     * @return PasswordEncoder object
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * Manages the configuration of the Authentication manager with
     * user credentials and roles.
     * <p>
     * The AuthenticationManager processes any authentication request.
     *
     * @param auth AuthenticationManagerBuilder object
     * @throws Exception exception
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Manages the configuration for specific http request.
     *
     * @param http HttpSecurity request
     * @throws Exception exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                //configure security for pages
                .antMatchers(new String[]{"/login", "/accessDenied"}).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('admin')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                //creates login form
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/accessDenied")
                .usernameParameter("id_utente").passwordParameter("password")
                //catches exceptions http 403 response
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
    }

    /**
     * Manages the storage of user credentials inside database
     *
     * @return The authenticationProvider Object
     */
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider()
    {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver()
    {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }
}
```

**Custom user detail service**

```
@Service("securityUserDetailService")
public class SecurityUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    UtentiService utentiService;

    /**
     * Manages the load of a user along with
     * ID and password.
     *
     * @param s user id
     * @return UserDetail object with ID and password
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException If user is not found in the system
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(s);

        Utenti user = utentiService.findUserById(id);
        if(user == null)
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with id " + s + " not found");
        }

        return new User(Integer.toString(user.getId_utente()), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
    }

    /**
     * Determines which roles a particular user has
     *
     * @param user The user for which to find roles
     * @return List containing all roles related to the user
     */
    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Utenti user)
    {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + user.getQualifica()));

        return authorities;
    }
}
```

I do not know where the problem is, but I think it might be in the global configuration, I may be missing something about this method as I am new to Spring security:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}
```

How these configurations hav to be changed in order to authenticate user with JDBC and MySQL table?
And There is a preferred way to insert the first (normally admin) user?

**EDIT**

Logs from spring security state:

```
15:27:38.660 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: For input string: ""
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:219) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:95) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:141) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at com.entsorgafin.service.impl.security.SecurityUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(SecurityUserDetailService.java:36) ~[classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 43 more
```

In particular, lines:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at com.entsorgafin.service.impl.security.SecurityUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(SecurityUserDetailService.java:36) ~[classes/:?]
```

state that the error comes from the line

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

In the `loadUserByUsername` method, now i do not understand how this method is getting an empty string "" instead of the "2" I type in the form.

**Form Page**

```
<c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />

<div class="leftBar">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <p>testo esempio</p>
</div>
<div class="rightBar">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
        <form:form method="post" action="${loginUrl}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userId">ID utente</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userId" placeholder="ID utente">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userPwd">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPwd" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn">Accedi</button>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's already a lot of information here, but it'll be (even) easier to diagnose the problem if you add some Spring Security logs. Put "logging.level.org.springframework.security=debug" into your application.properties, run the application again, try to log in and add the logs that you see.

Comment: @neofelis, thanks in advance, I added logs coming from Spring Security. I used log4j2 to take them, i also edited the post accordingly with the new discovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is with your form page.

From the [MDN reference for the HTML input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefname):

> Consider the name a required attribute (even though it's not). If an input has no name  specified, or name is empty, the input's value is not submitted with the form!

None of your `<input>` elements have names, so nothing is getting submitted. (You can turn on the developer tools in your browser and inspect the request that it's sending to make sure that this is, in fact, the problem.)

In your configuration (specifically the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method in `SecurityConfiguration`) you are using the `usernameParameter` and `passwordParameter` methods. So the input field for the username should have `name="id_utente"` and the input field for the password should have `name="password"`. (If I understand what those methods do, anyway; I haven't used them myself.)

There is one further issue with your configuration which is *probably* not related to your current problem. (Maybe there are also other issues -- I'm fairly new to Spring Security myself -- but this is one.) You use the methods `jdbcAuthentication`, `authenticationProvider` *and* `userDetailsService` on your `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. You only need one of them. Remove the other two. This will help with readability, but that's not the only reason. When you configure multiple authentication providers Spring will try them in sequence. In your specific case, I think this means that you're hitting the database multiple times per failed login attempt.

Edit: [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43996387/13018875) helped me identify the issue, and the relevant bit of Spring Security documentation is [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form), specifically Example 53.

Comment: You were totally right, my fault having forgotten 'name' attribute inside input tags. Besides I tried to log in with only the line 
  auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
and it actually works with no problems, so only one method is necessary as you said, thanks again.